# Forgot password emails not sending in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement password reset functionality.

My urls contains:

```
url(r'^password_reset/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {'template_name': 'resetpassword.html', 'post_reset_redirect' : '/password_reset/mailed/'},
name="password_reset"),

url(r'^password_reset/mailed/$',
'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done',{'template_name': 'resetpassword_mailed.html'}),

url(r'^password_reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13})-(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', 
{'post_reset_redirect' : '/password_reset/complete/'}),

url(r'^password_reset/complete/$', 
'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete',{'template_name': 'resetpassword_complete.html'}),
```

and settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply@mysite.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply@mysite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587    
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

URL routing works just fine, however email are not being sent.

If I try to use Django shell and test sending:

```
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', to=['test@email.com'])
email.send()
```

And it works just fine as well.

How could I fix this? I don't get any error messages and don't know how could I debug this.

**UPD**
I have found out that in django/contrib/auth/views.py: password_reset method I always go to

```
else:
    post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)
```

part and never to actually sending email. How's that?

```
if post_reset_redirect is None:
    post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_done')
else:
    post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = password_reset_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print 'reset form valid'
        opts = {
            'use_https': request.is_secure(),
            'token_generator': token_generator,
            'from_email': from_email,
            'email_template_name': email_template_name,
            'subject_template_name': subject_template_name,
            'request': request,
            'html_email_template_name': html_email_template_name,
        }
        if is_admin_site:
            opts = dict(opts, domain_override=request.get_host())
        form.save(**opts)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)
```

Comment: are you using `manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: @Anentropic yes, why?

Comment: Try `email.send(fail_silently=False)` and post the error here.

Comment: @Leistungsabfall there is no error in email.send(fail_silently=False).
Email sending works fine from the shell

Comment: Set breakpoint at django/contrib/auth/forms.PasswordResetForm send_mail method and check if all goes well there.

Comment: @amureki updated the question, maybe you'd have some comments?

Comment: @SeledkaLebedka post_reset_redirect is just a variable it not redirects you anywhere. Redirect actually at the end of the method. You should check deeper at password_reset_form, as I said before, there is send_mail method is calling inside save() method.

Comment: @amureki yeah, indeed. The problem was in my mistake at the template. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If the user has no password (e.g. created with `create_user()`), the password reset won't send anything!  Make sure you create a password as well via:
`password = User.objects.make_random_password()`

Then, you also need to set the password and save, for example

```
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a trivial question but the user you are using to test has a valid email set? If it's empty will not send the email neither raise an exception.

Check the [send method source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/message.py#L286).

Other way to see if the email is being generated is use the console backend:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

and look at the console because the email should appears there.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the user has a valid email.
I've tried what you suggested about EMAIL_BACKEND and nothing has changed, nothing has appeared in the console.

Comment: @seledkalebedka, Are you submitting the data by POST to "password_reset" url? Django will send the email only when "method == 'POST'" and "form.is_valid()"
Have you solved it already? Thanks